# Chef - using a local repository with Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I want to create a local repository for Ubuntu using dkpg-dev and the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal), and install with the Chef Package resource. However, it fails on the package step with the following message:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
m4 sendmail-base sendmail-cf sendmail-bin procmail sensible-mda sendmail
STDERR: E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
```

It is an offline EC2 instance, so I am not able to run any commands to update apt-keys after the packages are moved onto the instance.

Is there a way around this error using without using a bash resource to feed "Y"s, or dpkg -R?

Comment: Your problem doesn't seem to be related to Chef. You're missing a key for the repo you've created, so you can't install any packages from it yet. There's probably an apt-add-key step or something you're missing.

Comment: That is right, as explained above. My question is whether there is a way for the chef package resource specifically to ignore it. The packages can still be installed using a bash resource to answer the prompts. I guess the title could have been more specific, sorry.

Comment: Have you checked out the documentation for the package resource? You can feed it both additional parameters (something like --no-prompt --always-X) as well as a response file and response variables specifically for apt.

Comment: That was it, via the options property. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the options parameter of the package resource to disregard the authentication problem.

```
package [ 'package-a','package-b','package-c' ] do
  action :upgrade
  options '--force-yes'
end
```